# Fire chipSelectionChanges on init

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like fire the observable chipSelectionChanges, on init, in selecting a chip.

```
<mat-chip-list selectable multiple >
  <mat-chip
    *ngFor="let chipElement of chips"
    [selected]="chipElement.selected"
  >
    {{ chipElement.name | titlecase }}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>

@ViewChild(MatChipList) matChipList!:MatChipList;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.matChipList.chipSelectionChanges.subscribe(console.log);
}
```

If chipElement.selected = true, I would like fire chipSelectionChanges.

How can I make ?

Comment: Please do not put solutions in the question itself. That's not the right place. Solutions go as answers below.

Comment: @Dharman [that solution](/revisions/73821239/2) is just a [link to another question on SO](/q/39787038) maybe it would be better to close it as a duplicate rather than posting a link-only answer?

Comment: Thx, i'm news here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Generally [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) queries are resolved completely in [afterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) hook. For a better explanation of why see [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-the-viewchild-and-viewchildren-decorators-in-angular-10/)

If you want to resolve queries before afterViewInit, preferably in [onInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)
there is a flag to Viewchild decorator, `static`. Passing `static` true will resolve the queries before component is initialized completely. You you can access the value in onInit. **Eg**

```
@ViewChild(MatChipList, { static: false }) matChipList!:MatChipList;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.matChipList.chipSelectionChanges.subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Another **hacky** way would be to simply wrap the listener in `setTimeOut` like this

```
@ViewChild(MatChipList) matChipList!:MatChipList;
onInit() {
  this.matChipList.chipSelectionChanges.subscribe(console.log);
}
```

for complete explanation, see article [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-the-viewchild-and-viewchildren-decorators-in-angular-10/)

Comment: I tried your solution, but i have this error : src_app_bar_bar_module_ts.js:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: SetTimeOut hacky works :)

Comment: Yeah, again. View child elements are properly initialized in afterviewInit. using static false does get the query resolved in onInit but some properties are still uninitialized and that is why settimeout works because it delays the execution of that call

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely listen to `change` Output directly from HTML.

```
<mat-chip-list selectable multiple (change)="yourFunction">
  <mat-chip
    *ngFor="let chipElement of chips"
    [selected]="chipElement.selected"
  >
    {{ chipElement.name | titlecase }}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Typescript:

```
yourFunction(event: MatChipListChange ) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand but (change) doesn't work. I used selectionChange on mat-chip for the same effect. I will try for your solution.